# First option selected by default in select tag when using templateURL with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html-select

I am facing an issue I cannot quite understand with AngularJS.

I have a fairly simple select which behaves differently in two of my directives. In my first directive with templateURL, it selects the first option by default whereas it does not in my second one:

```
.directive("inputFieldSelectTpl", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '=',
    },
    "templateUrl": "inputFieldSelect.tpl.html",
    "link": function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.opta = attrs.opta;
      scope.optb = attrs.optb;
    }
  };
});

.directive("inputFieldSelect", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '=',
    },
    template: function(elem, attrs) {
      var template =
      '<select ng-model="ngModel">'+
      '<option value='+attrs.opta+'>'+attrs.opta+'</option>'+
      '<option value='+attrs.optb+'>'+attrs.optb+'</option>'+
      '</select>';
      return template;
    }
  };
});
```

with inputFieldSelect.tpl.html:

```
<select ng-model="ngModel">
  <option value={{opta}}>{{opta}}</option>
  <option value={{optb}}>{{optb}}</option>
</select>
```

I just cannot figure out why. I have read that I could add an empty option tag in templateURL to avoid this auto select but it adds an empty option which I would like to avoid for a mandatory form field. Is it normal or an angularJS bug?

(I do not mind about my model not having the select default value as I can force this later on.)

Here is a complete and simple Punker: http://plnkr.co/edit/tz5s6vjI83VyTKGycTzg

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I managed to make it work using a Prelink instead of a link:

http://plnkr.co/edit/zhcDBwJbzJ9Ilr0qfrLp?p=preview

```
  "link": {
    pre: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.opta = attrs.opta;
      scope.optb = attrs.optb;
    }
  }
```

I would say that this function has to be executed before the angularJS select directive otherwise its options are somewhat unknown, hence this undefined behaviour selecting the first value.

Answer (score 0):

If you attach a controller in the directive you can initialize the variable in the directive.  I modified the Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/bQwkV83jhPPsiqTs4nsK?p=preview

The change:

```
  controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.ngModel="Monetary"
  }
```

Hopefully this works for what you are doing?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, actually I might have not explained my issue that well but my problem is the opposite: I want to use templateURL but it selects the first option of my select by default.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Could you add a "select option" option in your template, and have it disabled?  This way it is selected by default, but once another option is selected, you can't select it.  I updated my plunker with this.

Comment: Cool, this is actually a good "option" and it adds a Placeholder too, but it does not explain why AngularJS behaves like this though, I will try to see if it still comply to my form validation as an empty option is pre-selected.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Alas I don't know why the blank option doesn't appear with the template...